# Variable is already defined in the scope

Tags: java

I just wanted to say that I am new at java and I have been practicing and getting a LITTLE better. I'm trying to make a very simple banking system where you have the options to create an account, deposit and withdraw money. I'm a bit stuck at this current time though and hoping someone could help me out.

I'm trying to take input from the user and then create a new object instance with the user input in the parameters and it's giving me and error. Here is the code line it's giving me the error on, thank you!

It's prompting me with the error on the: bankAccount object creation line for the userName String variable.

```
case 1:
                System.out.println("Please Enter Your Name: ");
                String userName = input.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Please Enter a 4 digit pin number: ");
                int pinNumber = input.nextInt();
                int accountNumber = rand.nextInt(5100 - 1100) + 1000;
                System.out.println("Account Created with the following credentials:\n " +
                        "Name: " + userName + "\n" +
                        "Account Number: " + accountNumber + "\n" +
                        "Pin Number: " + pinNumber);
                bankAccount userName = new bankAccount(userName, accountNumber);
                break;
```

Comment: You already declared a string named `userName`. You can't have two different variables with the same name.

Comment: Also as a general remark since you're still learning, please start the names of your classes with a capital letter and use camel casing, such as `BankAccount`

Answer (score 2):

With java, you cannot make a local variable with the same name, even though the data types are different.

`userName` is already used as a String variable so you cannot make a new `bankAccount` named `userName`. You could name it `userAccount` though.

Example:

```
 bankAccount userAccount = new bankAccount(userName, accountNumber);
```

You could then add this to an array or Map to reference that particular userAccount later.

```
bankAccount[] accounts = new bankAccount[];
//several lines of code
bankAccount[0] = userAccount;
```

or

```
Map<String, bankAccount> bankAccount accounts = new HashMap<String, bankAcount>();
//several lines of code
bankAccount.put(userAccount.userName, userAccount);
```

To retrieve the userAccount of a certain user, you can do this later in the program.

```
bankAccount userAccount = bankAccount.get("bob");
```

This is get the bankAccount that has `"bob"` as the userName.

I imagine you're doing this as an independent project. If you have the time, it could be a good idea to learn some java from [codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/) to get a better understanding of the basics.

Comment: well I want the object name to be the userName the user inputs if that makes sense?

So like if I enter "bob" as the userName, then I want to create an object of the bankAccount class by doing 

    bankAccount bob = new bankAccount();

Comment: @Justin1989 it doesn't make sense to call a `bankAccount` variable `userName`, or `user_name`, for that matter. It's a bank account, not a name.

Comment: Making the String object `userName` makes sense. The `bankAccount` object should probably be called `userAccount` though

Comment: I'm not wanting to call my bankAccount "userName" I'm wanting to create a new object using the info stored information the String variable data in userName

Comment: If that's the case then change 
 `bankAccount userName = new bankAccount(userName, accountNumber);` to  `bankAccount userAccount = new bankAccount(userName, accountNumber);` That should give you what you want.

Comment: @Justin1989 it's not possible to name variables based on another variable. You wouldn't be able to refer to those variables either, since the name would be decided at runtime.

Comment: But if I wanted to call a method to let's say add money then i would have to use userAccount.depositMoney(); where as if the userName data was used creating the object - let's say "bob' then I could do bob.depositMoney(); because what if I want to create another account? then it will try to create a duplicate object of userAccount. I hope I'm making sense :\

Comment: @Justin1989 you couldn't write `bob.depositMoney()`, because you wouldn't know the name is bob. See how that doesn't work even in theory? What you can do is create a `Map<String, BankAccount>` to associate a username with an account. I recommend you to read more and write less, you're missing some important details from basic Java syntax and idioms.

Comment: I get what you're trying to do now. That is not something you should do in this situation. After you make the `bankAccount`, you can tell whose account it is by using `userAccount.userName`.

Comment: @Thatalent, try updating your answer showing a working example that includes both `bankAccount userAccount = new bankAccount(userName, accountNumber);` and how to get the username using `userAccount.userName`

Comment: re naming the object as userName, you would typically call the object a set name eg bankAccount, and then access the properties on it as needed.  You would not change the name of the object in the code if you entered a different userName (i think this is what your comment re "bob" meant).  Declaring the object name as a variable is a key part of Java, creating a pointer to the object (an instance of bankAccount in this case) that can then have compile time checks made on it.

Answer (score 0):

You have created the variable userName twice in line number 2 and 10. in java you cannot create the same variable name even though they have two types.