# Customizing RestTemplateBuilder

Tags: spring-boot, apache-httpclient-5.x

Customizing RestTemplateBuilder

Based on the suggestion in
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/35658

Can someone help me understand how the settings are passed?
What is the default SslBundle in Spring boot?

```
ClientHttpRequestFactorySettings settings = new ClientHttpRequestFactorySettings(Duration.ofSeconds(30),
                Duration.ofSeconds(30), (SslBundle) null);
```

Error says Variable 'settings' is already defined in the scope

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
    return builder
        .requestFactory((settings) -> new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(
            ClientHttpRequestFactories.get(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.class, settings)))
        .setConnectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(300))
        .setReadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(300))
        .build();
}
```

Is the below approach valid?

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {

    return restTemplateBuilder
            .requestFactory(() -> {
                ClientHttpRequestFactorySettings settings = new ClientHttpRequestFactorySettings(Duration.ofSeconds(30),
                        Duration.ofSeconds(30), true);
                return ClientHttpRequestFactories.get(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.class, settings);
            }).build();

}
```

Comment: Is this all your code? The error is a  Java, not Spring (or spring realted) error. It's essentially telling two variables are named the same. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52024574/variable-is-already-defined-in-the-scope

Comment: My questions are 

1. which settings are passed?
2. What is the default SslBundle in Spring boot?


@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
    return builder
        .requestFactory((settings) -> new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(
            ClientHttpRequestFactories.get(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.class, settings)))
        .setConnectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(300))
        .setReadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(300))
        .build();
}